# how to make 2 sequences of page numbers in MS Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2003, microsoft-word-2003, page-numbers

I need two sequences of page numbers in my document. One spanning the first few pages and a second sequence (starting at page number 1 again) right after that.

When i change the page numbers setting (insert->page numbers) it is applied to all pages in the document and renumbers all of them. Is there a way to set it for every (few) page(s) independently ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the page number sequence, you need a new section. Insert a section break where you want the change, then format the page number to deselect "Continue from previous section".